# ng-click isn't working on button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't see where I'm missing the point, but I can't call any functions with ng-click.

My HTML element:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :foto %><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="visitante[foto]" id="visitante_foto" ng-model="foto" ng-value="foto"/>
  <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
  </br>
  <button type="button" id="snap" ng-click="tirarFoto()">Tirar Foto</button>
</div>
```

My angular controller:

```
angular.module('controleVisitantes', ["angucomplete-alt"])
    .controller('controllerVisitantes', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tirarFoto = function () {

        var canvas, context;
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        $scope.foto = canvas.toDataURL();

    };
}])
```

EDIT:
I'm using Ruby on Rails.
I added ng-app to my `<body>` and ng-controller at `<div>` on `visitantes/new.html`

`console.log()` is working outside my function, but I can't call any functions.

I tried `<a>`, `<div>`, `<canvas>` with ng-click.

Comment: can you display the whole template?

Comment: Does the canvas element have the id of "canvas" or are you trying to select that element?  Does you html look like this `<canvas id="canvas">`?  +1 for AranS's comment, please post all your code.

Comment: your js looks fine, you could be missing something in your markup, check the ng-app and ng-controller definitions.

here is an example plunkr running your ng-click, the script works fine, and your button markkup is fine

https://plnkr.co/edit/4kwNhD?p=info

Comment: Actually I found where I was wrong.
I had 2 more closings divs and I broke my code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/4kwNhD?p=info
the script looks fine to me. check your markup, hopefully it looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="controleVisitantes">
    <div ng-controller="controllerVisitantes">
      <button type="button" id="snap" ng-click="tirarFoto()">Tirar Foto</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, I highly recommend following a style guide and standard naming conventions for your app. [John Papa's](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) style guide is very popular in the angular community but there are others. This will be crucial when your app grows in size and/or as your team gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the file for the controller in the index.html?

Since there is only a little bit of the code I can only guess.
Is the template nested inside the correct ng-controller or linked to the controller through the correct routing?
Also if you are using the controllerAs syntax you would need to prefix the function call with the name(vm for example)

```
<button type="button" id="snap" click="vm.tirarFoto()">Tirar Foto</button>ng-
```